# How do I terminate a Java program if a certian condition isn't met?

Tags: java, terminate

Our project is to write a program that will validate credit card numbers. I am wanting to put a validation check at the beginning of the program so if the user enters a number that has less than 13 digits or more than 16 digits it displays an error message and then ends the program. I have read on here that the best (most graceful) way of doing it is to let the program run itself out. However, throughout the program I have other information displayed. So currently it will display the error message and then continue on with the program.

Any advice will be most helpful.

Comment: What's your current code and exact expected behaviour ?

Comment: No code, no good answer. Please provide your code

Answer (score 0):

I think that your best chance would be to use some form of a conditional statement that checks the number they enter. Depending on what you want, a nested if or if else statement might be best.

Comment: I have a method that checks the length. So what I'm doing is I have an if-else statement that checks the result of the method and displays the appropriate error message.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the number of digits using the following snippet:

```
int length = (int)(Math.log10(n)+1) //here n is your number
```

and further, you can continue to program like this:

```
if(length<13 || length>16) {
    //Print your error message
}

else {
    //Your program
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as you are in the `main()` method of the program you can just call `return` to exit your program. In all other places you can exit the execution of your program using `System.exit(1)` with 1 replaced by the exit code you want to return. Normally you will return 0 to indicate success (correct credit card number) and a different number to indicate failures like an incorrect credit card number.

Answer (score 0):

If the code is contained in a switch statement, a loop or an if statement you could always use the `break;` statement to exit you out of the code (loop, switch etc.)